# users().messages().list() seems to be capped out at 500 messages

Tags: python, jupyter, gmail-api

```
def main():
   
store = file.Storage('token.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Gmail API to fetch INBOX
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',labelIds = ['Label_21'], maxResults=600).execute()
messages = results.get('messages', [])
print (len(messages))
```

I am reading these specifically labelled messages that i get on a daily basis to archive them on my own custom application. I have more than 500 of these messages in my gmail account. But the api seems to be capped out at 500 of the most recent messages, even if i change maxResults to 600.

Does anyone else have this problem? Can anyone help please? I cant seem to find anything about .user.messages.list output limits in the docs. [Image for clarification/proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hcZf.png)

Answer (score 3):

```
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',labelIds = ['Label_21'], maxResults=600).execute()
```

Just found out about the query parameter in the list() method. I can just add this in q='before:yyyy/mm/dd' to pull results from the missing dates. Which would result in the following

```
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',labelIds = ['Label_21'], maxResults=600, q='before:yyyy/mm/dd').execute()
```